# Run django app via nginx+uwsgi in a subpath

Tags: django, nginx

I want to run a simple test project in a subdirectory alias on our development server. The basic setup is an nginx with a location that passes everything in a subdirectory to the wsgi application.

Django obviously does not understand that it runs in an subdirectory alias, which completely destroys URL generation and parsing.
I could not find any prefix-like setting in the docs and my google fu also did not help that much... so I'm asking here instead.

The only thing I did find was the setting FORCE_SCRIPT_NAME which at least fixes the URL generation. (see: http://docs.webfaction.com/software/django/config.html#mounting-a-django-application-on-a-subpath)
Sadly this does not fix the urlconf parsing, even though the mentioned site suggests that.

Is it possible to run a django application in a subdirectory alias and if so, how?

nginx config:

```
server {
        location /fancyprojectname/static {
                alias /srv/fancyprojectname/static;
        }

        location /fancyprojectname/ {
                uwsgi_pass unix://var/run/uwsgi/app/fancyprojectname/socket;
                include uwsgi_params;
        }
}
```

**Edit**

So, setting "uwsgi_param SCRIPT_NAME /fancyprojectname;" in the nginx location makes FORCE_SCRIPT_NAME unnecessary - sadly the URL matching still does not work.

```
from django.conf.urls import patterns, include, url

# Uncomment the next two lines to enable the admin:
from django.contrib import admin
admin.autodiscover()

urlpatterns = patterns('',
    # Uncomment the admin/doc line below to enable admin documentation:
    # url(r'^admin/doc/', include('django.contrib.admindocs.urls')),

    # Uncomment the next line to enable the admin:
    url(r'^admin/', include(admin.site.urls)),
)
```

What I think what is happening: As the admin regex starts with "^admin" and the actual URL is "fancyprojectname/admin/", Django can't match the URLs correctly, even though the SCRIPT_NAME is set.

**The solution**

So, it was indeed a problem with SCRIPT_NAME.

The [WSGI specification](http://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0333/) says the following:

> SCRIPT_NAME
>       The initial portion of the request URL's "path" that corresponds to the application object, so that the application knows its virtual
>   "location". This may be an empty string, if the application
>   corresponds to the "root" of the server.
>
> PATH_INFO
>   The remainder of the request URL's "path", designating the virtual "location" of the request's target within the application. This may be
>   an empty string, if the request URL targets the application root and
>   does not have a trailing slash.

Nginx does not set SCRIPT_NAME automatically, so this needs to be set in any case. Afterwards PATH_INFO is wrong, because in the default setup Nginx sets this to $document_uri, which would be the full URL.

"uwsgi_modifier1 30;" tells Nginx to set UWSGI_MODIFIER_MANAGE_PATH_INFO, which in turn tells UWSGI to strip off the SCRIPT_NAME of the PATH_INFO.

The combination of these settings seem to work, as Django can now generate AND match URLs correctly.

Comment: Please have a look at https://stackoverflow.com/a/40496307/1588163 There you will find the updated way to accomplish this

Comment: [See also: How to Mount Django App with uwsgi](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19475651/how-to-mount-django-app-with-uwsgi)

Comment: The link to `FORCE_SCRIPT_NAME` example isn't workable anymore; for anyone curios what was written there [here](https://web.archive.org/web/20210518225809/http://docs.webfaction.com/software/django/config.html#mounting-a-django-application-on-a-subpath) is a Wayback Machine last saved version.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

This is false:

> Django obviously does not understand that it runs in an subdirectory alias, which completely destroys URL generation and parsing.

Django *does* understand that, and deals with it transparently. The server should be setting `SCRIPT_NAME` itself: the fact that you find yourself using `FORCE_SCRIPT_NAME` shows that the problem lies in your Nginx configuration, rather than in Django.

I suspect that the issue is the use of `location`, rather than a more suitable directive. Unfortunately I'm no expert on Nginx/uwsgi. In Apache/mod_wsgi, you would do this:

```
WSGIScriptAlias /mysite /usr/local/django/mysite/apache/django.wsgi
```

to tell mod_wsgi that site starts at `mysite`, rather than the root. There is almost certainly a similar command with nginx/uwsgi.

Comment: Okay, I tried this with "uwsgi_param SCRIPT_NAME /fancyprojectname;" in nginx and this seems to "work", since I can now comment out FORCE_SCRIPT_NAME in the settings and the URLs are generated correctly - this still does not fix URL matching though. I'll append the current url configuration in the question.

Comment: It looks like it is working now - SCRIPT_NAME was not eneugh, setting "uwsgi_modifier1 30;" does it though. I have no idea what this setting does, but when I find out I'll update the question again and accept this as the valid answer. Thanks for the pointer!

Comment: I have to add that "uwsgi_modifier1 30" It is only half of the answer. The thing that worked for me was adding "env = DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE=my_app.settings" to my uwsgi.ini file

Answer (score 7):

**This approach (which worked in 2016) is now deprecated. It may still apply if you are running LTS software.**

> "Note: ancient uWSGI versions used to support the so called “uwsgi_modifier1 30” approach. Do not do it. it is a really ugly hack"
>
> See [Hosting multiple apps in the same process (aka managing SCRIPT_NAME and PATH_INFO](https://uwsgi-docs.readthedocs.io/en/latest/Nginx.html#hosting-multiple-apps-in-the-same-process-aka-managing-script-name-and-path-info)

**Original answer**

If this Nginx location block works when hosting the Django site at `http://www.example.com/` (your base domain):

```
location / {
    uwsgi_pass unix:/tmp/fancyprojectname.socket;
    include /etc/nginx/uwsgi_params;
}
```

Then this will work at `http://www.example.com/subpath/` (a subpath on your base domain):

```
location /subpath {
    uwsgi_pass unix:/tmp/fancyprojectname.socket;
    uwsgi_param SCRIPT_NAME /subpath; # explicitly set SCRIPT_NAME to match subpath
    uwsgi_modifier1 30; # strips SCRIPT_NAME from PATH_INFO (the url passed to Django)
    include /etc/nginx/uwsgi_params;
}
```

...and there is no need to set FORCE_SCRIPT_NAME in your Django settings.

**References:**

- Strayer's original comments and solution as posted in question.
- https://uwsgi-docs.readthedocs.org/en/latest/Nginx.html
- https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0333/ (full WSGI specification)

Comment: Thank you, now I have [Hatta wiki](http://hatta-wiki.org/) running in a subpath under nginx.

Comment: Don't forget to add "env = DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE=your_app.settings" to your uwsgi.ini file.

Answer (score 7):

Now that `uwsgi_modifier1 30` is **removed** in the latest versions of Nginx and uWSGI (and I didn't feel like using some hacky rewrite rules), I had to find a newer method to get it working:

*uWSGI config:*

```
[uwsgi]
# Requires PCRE support compiled into uWSGI
route-run = fixpathinfo:
```

*Nginx config*:

```
server {
    location /fancyprojectname/static {
        alias /srv/fancyprojectname/static;
    }

    location /fancyprojectname {
        uwsgi_pass unix://var/run/uwsgi/app/fancyprojectname/socket;
        uwsgi_param SCRIPT_NAME /fancyprojectname; # Pass the URL prefix to uWSGI so the "fixpathinfo:" route-rule can strip it out
        include uwsgi_params;
    }
}
```

**IF THAT DOESN'T FIX IT:** Try installing libpcre and libpcre-dev, then reinstall uwsgi with `pip install -I --no-cache-dir uwsgi`. uWSGI's internal routing subsystem requires the PCRE library to be installed *before* uWSGI is compiled/installed. [More information on uWSGI and PCRE.](https://stackoverflow.com/a/22645915/1951234)

Comment: this is the definitive solution

Comment: This solution is the best for django 3+ at least for me. Just have too modify all of my absolute paths and switch them for url/reverse filters.

Answer (score 0):

One can made both `SCRIPT_NAME` and `PATH_INFO` uWSGI variables to be filled correctly by nginx itself without setting `modifier1` header packet (which is deprecated and [doesn't work](https://github.com/unbit/uwsgi/pull/19) with python3 anymore) or relying on PCRE support in uWSGI server using the `route-run` parameter. Instead you can use the following trick rewriting an `$uri` nginx internal variable before including `uwsgi_params` file:

```
location /app_prefix/ {
    rewrite ^/app_prefix(.*) $1 break;
    include uwsgi_params;
    uwsgi_param SCRIPT_NAME /app_prefix;
    uwsgi_pass unix:/path/to/socket;
}
```

An alternative solution can be using the `manage-script-name` uWSGI server parameter ([command line example](https://stackoverflow.com/a/22642691/7121513), [config file example](https://stackoverflow.com/a/40496307/7121513)).