# How do I set subdirectory in nginx with Django

Tags: python, django, nginx, uwsgi

Environment:

- uwsgi
- nginx
- django 1.3

I'm using the domain `www.example.com` with Django and nginx, and I want to access the Django by **`www.example.com/abc/`** , but I don't know how to set the **subdirectory**.

This is the nginx conf file:

```
server {
        listen 80;
        server_name www.example.com;
        error_log /var/log/nginx/xxx.error_log info;

        root /home/web/abc;  # this is the directory of the django program

        location ~* ^.+\.(jpg|jpeg|png|gif|css|js|ico){
                root /home/web/abc;
                access_log off;
                expires 1h;
        }

        location ~ /abc/ {   # I want to bind the django program to the domian's subdirectory
                include uwsgi_params;
                uwsgi_pass 127.0.0.1:9000;
        }
}
```

When I open the website `www.example.com/abc/`, the django `urls.py` doesn't match, it only match the site like `^index$`.

How can I modify the nginx location to set django to `www.example.com/abc`?

Comment: Are you saying that you want to pass /abc/ to django? I.E. if the user visits www.example.com/abc/index.html do you want django to see `'/abc/index.html'` or just `'index.html'`?

Comment: @NathanVillaescusa I want to visit www.example.com/abc/index.html I want django to see the index.html

Answer (score 8, accepted):

According to the [uWSGI on Nginx](http://projects.unbit.it/uwsgi/wiki/RunOnNginx) docs, you just have to pass the `SCRIPT_NAME` to django.

```
location /abc {
    include uwsgi_params;
    uwsgi_pass 127.0.0.1:9000;
    uwsgi_param SCRIPT_NAME /abc;            
}
```

Django will still "see" `/abc`, but it should deal with it so that it gets stripped off before your urls are matched. You want this to happen, if django didn't see `/abc`, it would generate incorrect urls for your site and none of your links would work.

Comment: I also had to add "uwsgi_modifier1 30;" to make this work. Otherwise Django would try to match /abc/abc. Found this via http://stackoverflow.com/q/11292217/122661

Answer (score 2):

Now that `uwsgi_modifier1 30` is **removed** in the latest versions of Nginx and uWSGI, I had to use a newer method to get it working:

*uWSGI config:*

```
[uwsgi]
route-run = fixpathinfo:
```

*Nginx config*:

```
location /abc {
    include uwsgi_params;
    uwsgi_pass 127.0.0.1:9000;
    uwsgi_param SCRIPT_NAME /abc; # Pass the URL prefix to uWSGI so the "fixpathinfo:" route-rule can strip it out
}
```

**IF THAT DOESN'T FIX IT:** Try installing libpcre and libpcre-dev, then reinstall uwsgi with `pip install -I --no-cache-dir uwsgi`. uWSGI's internal routing subsystem requires the PCRE library to be installed *before* uWSGI is compiled/installed. [More information on uWSGI and PCRE.](https://stackoverflow.com/a/22645915/1951234)