# Rebuild uwsgi with pcre support

Tags: pcre, uwsgi

When running uwsgi I got the following message:

```
!!! no internal routing support, rebuild with pcre support !!!
```

I already have installed pcre (I think) with the following command:

```
sudo apt-get install libpcre3 libpcre3-dev
```

Why am I still getting this message even after I have installed the `pcre` package, if I need to reinstall `uwsgi` and activate `pcre`, how do I do it?

Also, does internal routing matter?

I assume it does or else the makers of `uwsgi` wouldn't have made the message come up. I am running `Ubuntu 12.04 LTS`.

Answer (score 111):

```
pip install uwsgi -I
```

Won't recompile the uwsgi binary, it just reinstalls the python egg. You need to rebuild the uwsgi binary with the pcre libraries.

```
sudo apt-get install libpcre3 libpcre3-dev
```

I think the easiest way is just to uninstall uwsgi and then run the pip installer again.

```
pip uninstall uwsgi
sudo apt-get remove uwsgi
```

then

```
pip install uwsgi
```

you should see pip run the setup.py script and a bunch of compiler messages.  The last message should show you something like this:

```
################# uWSGI configuration #################

pcre = True
kernel = Linux
malloc = libc
execinfo = False
ifaddrs = True
ssl = True
zlib = True
locking = pthread_mutex
plugin_dir = .
timer = timerfd
yaml = embedded
json = False
filemonitor = inotify
routing = True
debug = False
capabilities = False
xml = libxml2
event = epoll

############## end of uWSGI configuration #############
```

notice how pcre = true now

Comment: I followed the procedure and I don't get this output from the compiler. Do you know where can I find that configuration under ubuntu? I can't find it under /etc

Comment: I had the same problem but on CentOS. I installed `gcc*` and `pcre-devel` instead of `libpcre3` and `libpcre3-dev` and UWSGI works fine now.

Comment: You can also reinstall in one action with pip using `sudo /opt/storwizerest-venv/bin/pip install --force-reinstall -U --no-deps uwsgi`.  `--force-reinstall` will make `-U` reinstall the same version (and confusingly, `--force-reinstall` does nothing without `-U`), and `--no-deps` will prevent trying to update all dependencies.

Comment: what if one uses an alpine distribution?

Comment: @EsseTi: The guy is smart enough to figure how to find and install the libs on his distro: `apk install pcre pcre-dev`

Comment: @alanjds if i knew that was the name then yes, i haven't figured out where i can find the package names of alpine, and just trying out is not the best effort-solution.

Comment: Alpine packages index: https://pkgs.alpinelinux.org/packages?name=pcre&branch=edge (searched for `pcre` there)

Comment: I did not receive any of the output, but the solution did work for me.

Comment: This answer worked for me but needed to also add `--no-cache-dir` flag to the `pip install` from @alanjds 's answer

Answer (score 88):

`pip install uwsgi -I --no-cache-dir`

It reinstalls (`-I`) as @leech said, but ignores the compiled cache (`--no-cache-dir`) and recompiles the thing with the new libs.

Comment: This is the answer that worked for me, not the accepted answer.

Comment: This worked for me as well. This was one of those issues which I thought would only take a few minutes to figure out, but ended up taking hours.

Comment: Worked well for me, an all in one solution once you've done `pip uninstall uwsgi`. Thanks!

Comment: Worked for me after I thought to reboot the machine.

Answer (score 12):

```
pip uninstall uwsgi

sudo apt-get install libpcre3 libpcre3-dev

pip install uwsgi
```

I solved it with the above commands.

Answer (score 8):

Completing @alanjds answer, following is the process to add pcre support to your already installed uWSGI.

```
sudo apt-get install libpcre3 libpcre3-dev
pip install uwsgi -I --no-cache-dir
```

You do not need to uninstall uWSGI

Answer (score 4):

Did you try:

```
pip install uwsgi -I
```

The `-I` flag will force it to reinstall

Comment: ran the command and uwsgi reinstalled fine. But when I run it, i still get the same message about rebuilding with PCRE support.

Comment: @johnmic07 libpcre3-dev is enough and it's unlikely you need the routing

Comment: If you have a virtualenv setup (and I hope you do), your system might be confused between the local uwsgi, the global uwsgi (when you install with `sudo pip`), and perhaps the system (like `apt-get`) package.

I would build it in a virtualenv and then look for `pcre = yes` in the build output and find the program in the virtualenv `bin` directory

Comment: And, as jwalker said, if you don't use internal routing, you really don't need this.

Comment: I don't use internal routing so I won't worry about it. Hopefully no one else out there needs it either ;)

Comment: And with this particular setup (i was just going through a tutorial) I was not using virtualenv so I don't think that was the problem. Thanks though!

Comment: Use ``--no-cache-dir`` and ``-I`` and it will recompile.

Answer (score 2):

For those who want to fix this on `amazon linux 2` or any red hat family distros

First, Uninstall the `uwsgi` package

```
pip uninstall uwsgi
```

Then, Install `pcre` and `pcre-devel`

```
yum install pcre pcre-devel
```

Then, Reinstall the `uwsgi` package

```
pip install uwsgi
```

Answer (score 1):

Maybe you can check the uid & gid, I got this ERROR when I set them wrong.