# uWSGI nginx error : connect() failed (111: Connection refused) while connecting to upstream

Tags: nginx, uwsgi

I'm experiencing 502 gateway errors when accessing my IP on nginx(http://52.xx.xx.xx/), the logs simply says this:

> 2015/09/18 13:03:37 [error] 32636#0: *1 connect() failed (111: Connection refused) while connecting to upstream, client: xx.xx.xx.xx, server: xx.xx.xx.xx, request: "GET / HTTP/1.1", upstream: "uwsgi://127.0.0.1:8000", host: "xx.xx.xx.xx"

my nginx.conf file

```sh
# the upstream component nginx needs to connect to
upstream django {
    # server unix:///path/to/your/mysite/mysite.sock; # for a file socket
    server 127.0.0.1:8000; # for a web port socket (we'll use this first)
}

# configuration of the server
server {
    # the port your site will be served on
    listen      80;
    # the domain name it will serve for
    server_name xx.xx.xx.xx; # substitute your machine's IP address or FQDN
    charset     utf-8;

    access_log /home/ubuntu/test_django/nginx_access.log;
    error_log  /home/ubuntu/test_django/nginx_error.log;


    # max upload size
    client_max_body_size 75M;   # adjust to taste

    # Django media
    location /media  {
    alias /home/ubuntu/test_django/static/media/;  # your Django project's media files - amend as required
    }

    location /static {
    alias /home/ubuntu/test_django/static/; # your Django project's static files - amend as required
    }

    # Finally, send all non-media requests to the Django server.
    location / {
    uwsgi_pass  django;
    include  /home/ubuntu/test_django/uwsgi_params; # the uwsgi_params file you installed
    }
}
```

Is there anything wrong with nginx.conf file.....if i use default conf then it is working.

Comment: please post also your uWSGI configuration

Comment: did you find the answer?

Comment: yeh i used unix sockets...

Comment: facing the same issue..could you please elaborate .. if you have been able to solve the problem ...Thanks in advance

Comment: Installing PCRE libaries resolved my problem:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21669354/rebuild-uwsgi-with-pcre-support

Answer (score 7):

I resolved it by changing the socket configuration in uwsgi.ini
from `socket = 127.0.0.1:3031`, to `socket = :3031`. I was facing this issue when I ran nginx in one Docker container and uWSGI in another. If you are using command line to start uWSGI then do `uwsgi --socket :3031`.

Hope this helps someone stuck with the same issue, during deployment of a Django application using Docker.

Comment: where do i find the uwsgi.ini file? cant find it. or should i create it, and where i should be?

Comment: @itTech it won't be called `uwsgi.ini`, it will be called `<your_app>.ini`. Read more here: https://uwsgi-docs.readthedocs.io/en/latest/Configuration.html#ini-files

Answer (score 0):

change this address:

```
include  /home/ubuntu/test_django/uwsgi_params;
```

to

```
include     /etc/nginx/uwsgi_params;
```

Answer (score -1):

I ran into this issue when setting up the env by nginx + gunicorn and solve it by
adding '*' to ALLOWED_HOSTS or your specific domain.

Answer (score -1):

In my case with a debian server it worked moving:

```
include     /etc/nginx/uwsgi_params;
```

In the location tag in my nginx server config file, like this:

```
location /sistema {
    include     /etc/nginx/uwsgi_params;
    uwsgi_pass  unix://path/sistema.sock;
}
```

Also, check you have the following packages installed:
uwsgi-plugin-python

Answer (score -1):

`pip3 install uWSGI` did the trick for me :D