# 502 Bad getway error connect() to unix:/pathToProjectFolder/sample.sock failed (2: No such file or directory)

Tags: django, python-3.x, nginx

I am following this link to https://www.linode.com/docs/websites/nginx/deploy-django-applications-using-uwsgi-and-nginx-on-ubuntu-14-04 to host django application on nginx server.  I followed all steps mention in link but it show error while browsing site `:502 Bad gateway`.
I checked nginx error log file, it displays below error:

> 2017/03/04 07:09:21 [crit] 5131#0: *1 connect() to
>   unix:/pathToMyProjectFolder/sample.sock failed (2: No such file or
>   directory) while connecting to upstream, client: 127.0.0.1, server:
>   localhost, request: "GET / HTTP/1.1", upstream:
>   "uwsgi://unix:/pathToMyProjectFolder/sample.sock:", host:
>   "localhost:8087"

And sample.sock file is not actually present in my project folder.  I don't understand how this file will get created.

Comment: Check in the uwsgi log at /var/log/uwsgi.log

Comment: uwsgi.log displays  nodename: ubuntu
machine: x86_64
clock source: unix
detected number of CPU cores: 1
current working directory: /
detected binary path: /usr/local/bin/uwsgi
!!! no internal routing support, rebuild with pcre support !!!
user django not found.

Comment: I think, this is self explanatory. Check [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21669354/rebuild-uwsgi-with-pcre-support)

Comment: I tried http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21669354/rebuild-uwsgi-with-pcre-support link but it still gave me same error