# How to Mount Django App with uwsgi?

Tags: python, django, wsgi, uwsgi

I am using uwsgi to deploy a Django app.
I want the app to be accessed under:

```
SERVER_URL:PORT/APP_NAME
```

my uswgi configuration are:

```
[uwsgi]
http=:PORT
threads = 10
die-on-term=true
chdir = /dir/to/my/app/
home = /dir/to/my/app/
logto = /dir/to/log/LOG.log    
wsgi-file = /dir/to/my/app/main_package/wsgi.py
mount = /APP_NAME=/dir/to/my/app/main_package/wsgi.py
```

I can't get the mount to work.
I get the app under `SERVER_URL:PORT` and not under `SERVER_URL:PORT/APP_NAME`.

The logs I get are:

```
*** Starting uWSGI 1.9.14 (64bit) on [Sun Oct 20 11:12:49 2013] ***
compiled with version: 4.6.3 on 15 October 2013 13:08:46
os: Linux-3.2.0-29-generic #46-Ubuntu SMP Fri Jul 27 17:03:23 UTC 2012
nodename: SERVER_URL
machine: x86_64
clock source: unix
detected number of CPU cores: 1
current working directory: /
detected binary path: /dir/to/my/app/bin/uwsgi
uWSGI running as root, you can use --uid/--gid/--chroot options
*** WARNING: you are running uWSGI as root !!! (use the --uid flag) *** 
*** WARNING: you are running uWSGI without its master process manager ***
your processes number limit is 15886
your memory page size is 4096 bytes
detected max file descriptor number: 1024
building mime-types dictionary from file /etc/mime.types...530 entry found
lock engine: pthread robust mutexes
uWSGI http bound on :8016 fd 4
spawned uWSGI http 1 (pid: 21029)
uwsgi socket 0 bound to TCP address 127.0.0.1:60322 (port auto-assigned) fd 3
Python version: 2.7.3 (default, Apr 10 2013, 06:31:07)  [GCC 4.6.3]
Set PythonHome to /dir/to/my/app/
Python main interpreter initialized at 0x22c6830
python threads support enabled
your server socket listen backlog is limited to 100 connections
your mercy for graceful operations on workers is 60 seconds
mapped 165584 bytes (161 KB) for 10 cores
*** Operational MODE: threaded ***
WSGI app 0 (mountpoint='') ready in 0 seconds on interpreter 0x22c6830 pid: 21028 (default app)
mounting /dir/to/my/app/main_package/wsgi.py on /APP_NAME
WSGI app 1 (mountpoint='/APP_NAME') ready in 0 seconds on interpreter 0x276e1b0 pid: 21028
*** uWSGI is running in multiple interpreter mode ***
spawned uWSGI worker 1 (and the only) (pid: 21028, cores: 10)
```

I also tried to delete `wsgi-file` from the uswgi configuration, and leave only the `mount` configuration. I got:

```
mounting /dir/to/my/app/main_package/wsgi.py on /APP_NAME
WSGI app 0 (mountpoint='/APP_NAME') ready in 0 seconds on interpreter 0x24ae780 pid: 11515 (default app)
```

And still the app wasn't mounted correctly.

How do I mount my app?

P.S.
I want to avoid using nginx.

Comment: added in the original message

Comment: no idea, either.. hope [this](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/howto/deployment/wsgi/uwsgi/) page helps... btw I think `nginx` is worth trying.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

nginx cannot pass the correct SCRIPT_NAME (and PATH_INFO) to uWSGI. You need to tell uWSGI to make translation by itself with --manage-script-name

By the way you do not need wsgi-file as mount already loads it