# Django - problems with static files when running in subpath

Tags: python, django, nginx

I have django app running in subpath `example.com/api/`. Most of it is rest API (I use django-rest-framework), and all requests are working correctly. But static files has wrong paths everywhere - in admin panel, and in requests page (in django-rest-framework you have frontend to investigate things). Django somehow thinks, that all static files are in `example.com/back/static/`, when they are in `example.com/api/back/static/`.

Also `example.com/api/admin` redirects to `example.com/admin/login/`, but after manually going to `example.com/api/admin/login/` everything works smoothly (but still there are no styles).

My stack is nginx + Django 2.0.5 running in docker container.

Nginx configuration:

```
location /api/ {
    proxy_pass            http://localhost:8000/;
    proxy_read_timeout    90;
    proxy_connect_timeout 90;
    proxy_set_header      Host $host;
    proxy_set_header      X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
    proxy_set_header      X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
    proxy_set_header      Proxy "";
}
```

When it comes to Django `STATIC_URL` is set to `os.path.join(BASE_DIR, "static/")`, `FORCE_SCRIPT_NAME` is not set, but when set, it's not working at all.

Any ideas?

**[Update]**

After some hours of fight, I gave up. The problem is connected with uwsgi not recognizing that it's running in subpath. Here are some links which can be useful for someone with similar problem:

[Run django app via nginx+uwsgi in a subpath](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11292217/run-django-app-via-nginxuwsgi-in-a-subpath)

[Running Django on a subpath](https://integricho.github.io/2014/02/22/running-django-on-a-subpath/)

[Serving multiple Django applications with Nginx and Gunicorn](http://michal.karzynski.pl/blog/2013/10/29/serving-multiple-django-applications-with-nginx-gunicorn-supervisor/)

[Django WSGI routing](http://spazzy757.com/wsgi-routing/)

I gave up and just created separate subdomain for this project.

Comment: Do you want the django app to serve its own static files or do you want nginx to serve them (better)?

Comment: @schwobaseggl I want to use django to serve its own static files

Comment: Your `STATIC_URL` setting looks like you want it to be your `STATIC_ROOT` setting. Then set  `STATIC_URL` to `/api/back/static/`. Make sure to call `collectstatic` on the server. Also set your `LOGIN_URL` setting to `/api/admin/login/`

Comment: It doesn't work, seems like django is ommiting 'api' subpath in this requests.

Comment: you must declare STATIC_ROOT and STATIC_URL in settings.py of your site.

Comment: @vorujack I did it, It seams that problem is in generating paths - django thinks that it's in root path, nginx passes everything to it, and it works, but when django generates urls, it doesn't care about `api/` subpath and omits it.

Comment: for static use /api/static/ in settings static_url

Answer (score 3):

This is a known [issue](https://code.djangoproject.com/ticket/25598) in Django.

**Expected behavior**

Outside world (nginx\uwsgi\whatever) should have `SCRIPT_NAME` header (which would be equal to `/api` in your case) and forward it to Django.

Django should respect this header and add it for the URLs generated with `{%url ... %}` tag (which it does already) AND for static file links generated with `{% static ... %}` (which does not work, see mentioned issue).

To workaround this you can append prefix directly to `STATIC_URL`: `STATIC_URL = '/api/static'`... But this is a dirty hack, I agree. The proper way is to to have it fixed on Django side.

Also see https://stackoverflow.com/a/57009760/1657819, may be a bit related

Answer (score 1):

If you `proxy_pass` a location in Nginx and add a URI to your `proxy_pass` directive you are telling Nginx to remove that from the original request URL and replace that part of the request URI with your `proxy_pass` URI. So this:

```
location /api/ {
    proxy_pass            http://localhost:8000/;
```

Tells Nginx that a request to example.com/api/path/to/whatever/ should be proxied to http://localhost:8000/path/to/whatever/

If you want the original unaltered request URI passed to the proxy then remove the `/` from the end of the `proxy_pass` directive

Answer (score 0):

add this code to your nginx configuration:

```
location /static/ {
    alias /path/static/;
}
```

you should define the location of static files, in order to read it.